# How to move 2 vlaues (String and double) from one activity to another?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have a simple idea for APP and I'm totally beginner. my idea is to create an app that have 2 activity. First activity will request the user to enter his/her name(String) and weight(Double) and then the user will click a button that will transfer the data to Activity 2 which will display the name as it is and the weight will be multiplied by 0.0425. Here is the code I have so far.

Activity 1:

```
package com.example.abdulelah.newapp1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText4;
    EditText editText3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String name = editText.getText().toString();
                        Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(editText4.getText().toString());

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("myname", name);
                        intent.putExtra("weight", value1);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }


}
```

Activity 2:

```
package com.example.abdulelah.newapp1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("myname");
        Double value1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("weight", 0);


        textView.setText(name);
        editText.setText((int) (value1*0.0425));
    }

}
```

waiting for valuable assistance.

Comment: Is it not working? You can pass data using `putExtra`, which you are already using

Comment: No it is not working the app shutdown when I click the button.

Comment: Have you defined mainactivity2 in manifest?

Comment: yes II believe, because when I remove the double part from the app it works. so the name only will work, but the issue here is when I add the double part to move two data to next activity.

Comment: Logcat?.........